# Trigger on update of an attribute of a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I created computer audit application. When I ran my application, it shows computer accessories on browser like computerName, osVersion, lastAudit, model, totalMemory, processor, userName.

I have created a database in SQL Server 2008 with one table `Computers`. When a value is inserted into that table, I need to update the table value in the column. In an attempt to try this, I'm using a trigger. However, I do not fully understand how triggers work.

Can someone please show me how to accomplish this.

My table has these columns:

```
id, computerName, osVersion, lastAudit, model, totalMemory, processor, userName
```

I know that in this code something wrong or missing but I am not able to complete this. Please  help me in this regard.

```
  CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger
  ON computers
  AFTER UPDATE
   AS 
   BEGIN
declare @id as int
declare @computerName as varchar(100)
declare @osVersion as varchar(100)
declare @lastAudit as datetime
declare @model as varchar(100)
declare @totalMemory float
declare @processor as varchar(100)
declare @userName as varchar(100)
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
if update(id)
BEGIN
    insert into computers values(@id,@computerName,@osVersion,@lastAudit,@model,
                            @totalMemory,@processor,@userName,'Update')

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    END
    GO
```

Comment: Why do you want to insert another row into the same table when you update a row in the `Computers` table? What's the point? For an audit, you would typically insert a row *into a separate `Audit` table* - not into the same table as you've updated your data in....

Comment: ok,firstly I am trying to update the row but it was not work so that I am trying this code.

Comment: ok,thanks your comment helpful for me. Next point is that I want my table automatically update when new computer added so can you edit my trigger code in this regard's.

Comment: Added an answer - it's not really clear to me if you want to do something after `INSERT` or after `UPDATE` (or both), and it's not really clear ***what*** you want to do (e.g. which columns you want to update with what values) in your trigger - I just showed the basics of a trigger - adapt as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply update one or more columns of your existing table when new rows are being inserted (or when they are updated? Not quite clear...), try a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigUpdateTable
ON dbo.Computers
AFTER INSERT  -- or AFTER UPATE or AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  -- do whatever you want to do on INSERT and/or UPDATE
  UPDATE 
      dbo.Computers
  SET 
      LastAudit = GETDATE()
  FROM 
      dbo.Computers c
  INNER JOIN 
      Inserted i ON c.id = i.id
```

One very important point to remember: SQL Server triggers are ***not*** called per row that is affected - but per statement, and if your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement affects multiple rows, you'll have multiple entries in the `Inserted` pseudo table and you need to be able to deal with that fact in your trigger

Comment: I am getting your point. Here I confused, which trigger I would use.I cleared my confusion from your post. Thanks a lot.